# Showing uniqueness of a best approximation in a Hilbert space.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

To introduce some context, here I am dealing with a *Hilbert space* H and a linear and closed subspace $S$ of $H$ such that $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is an orthonormal basis for $S$. Previously, I have shown that the vector $$ y = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \langle x,b_k\rangle b_k$$
Satisfies the equality $\| x- y\| = \inf_{z \in S} \| x- z \|.$ I am now trying to prove that this $y$ is unique.

To do so, my thinking go as follows:

Suppose there exists a distinct element $y' \neq y$ ($y' \in S$) such that $\| x - y'\| = \inf_{z \in S} \| x - z \| = \|x-y\|.$ To prove what's wanted, one should find a contradiction (essentialy, should find that $y = y'$).  My only idea to reach such a contradiction is to apply the parallelogram law to the vectors $x-y$ and $x-y'.$ Doing so,

$$ \| x - y\ + x - y'\|^2 + \| (x-y)-(x-y') \|^2 = 2(\|x-y\|^2 + \|x-y'\|^2) $$

But it is easy to see that $x-y+x-y' = 2x - y - y'$ and $(x-y)-(x-y') = y' - y$ and $\|x-y'\|^2 = \|x-y\|^2$, by hipothesis. Thus, the equation above is equivalent to

$$ \| 2x-y-y'\|^2 + \|y' - y\|^2 = 4\|x-y\|^2 \Leftrightarrow \| y' - y \|^2 = 4\|x-y\|^2 - \|2x-y-y'\|^2. $$

Now, the desired result would come if I could prove that $4\|x-y\|^2 = \|2x-y-y'\|^2$ but I don't see how to do this...

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uniqueness of orthogonal projection in closed subspace of Hilbert space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4506827/uniqueness-of-orthogonal-projection-in-closed-subspace-of-hilbert-space)

Answer (score 1):

A few comments first:

- If you prove that $y=y'$ you already got what you want; phrasing it as a contradiction only obscures the argument.
- Nowhere in your argument do you use that $y,y'$ minimize the distance.
- And, also, nowhere in your argument do you use that $S$ is convex; and the uniqueness can fail for non-convex $S$.

With the above considered, a typical argument is as follows. It uses the paralellogram identity in a similar way as you did. The crucial piece of information is that, since $S$ is convex,
$$
\Big\|\frac{y+y'}2-x\Big\|\geq\|y-x\|.
$$
Then
\begin{align}
\|y-y'\|^2
&=\|y-x-(y'-x)\|^2=2\|y-x\|^2+2\|y'-x\|^2-\|y+y'-2x\|^2\\[0.3cm]
&=4\|y-x\|^2-4\Big\|\frac{y+y'}2-x\Big\|^2\\[0.3cm]
&\leq4\|y-x\|^2-4\|y-x\|^2=0.
\end{align}
So $y'=y$.

Comment: I know convexity of $S$ is equivalent to $S$ having an orthonormal basis, but is there a way to justify the inequality $\| \frac{y+y'}{2} - x \| \geqslant \| y - x \| $ using the fact that $S$ admits an orthonormal basis? I am looking for an answer that avoids convexity at all costs, as I stated in my original post (linked above)

Comment: The property holds because of convexity. Convexity does hold in subspaces by definition. What do you mean  by "$S$ admits an orthonormal basis"  if $S$ is not a subspace?

Comment: Well, according to my lecturer, the whole point of this exercise is to show that the convexity of $S$ can be replaced by the fact that $S$ has an orthonormal basis and thus, it makes no sense to use convexity $(?)$.

Comment: Well, the problem is that if by "have an orthonormal basis" you literally mean "have an orthonormal basis" what you are trying to prove is false. For instance, let $S=\{e_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis and take $x=(e_1+e_2)/2$. Then $y=e_1$ and $y'=e_2$ both minimize $\operatorname{dist}(x,S)$. No one considers orthonormal bases outside of subspaces, as it makes little sense.

Comment: I am sorry, maybe I wasn't really clear in my last comment: $S$ is supposed to be a closed subspace of the Hilbert space $H$, and additionally, $S$ must have an orthonormal basis. This is all the information I am given and I must work with, specially without invoking convexity. What I am trying to say is that your answer isn't what I am looking for simply because you invoke convexity (which in a normal scenario would be more than valid).

Comment: But then I fail to see your problem. If $S$ is a subspace and $y,y'\in S$, then by definition of subspace the linear combination $(y+y')/2$ is in $S$ (that is, every subspace is convex). It seems like  for some mysterious reason you want to ignore that such a linear combination is also a convex combination, and that it is convexity and not linearity that is crucial for the argument.

Comment: I understand your point. I will try to speak with the lecturer and give the feedback when possible (by the way, your idea makes absolute sense to me) - if the feedback is positive, I will just mark your answer as right!

Comment: No worries, whatever helps you better.